# When do I need to define dunder class attributes?

Tags: python

I see that some people, like pydantic devs, use a lot of class dunder attributes defined by themselves. For example, check BaseModel [here](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/main/pydantic/main.py)

So the simplified version there.

```
class BaseModel(metaclass=_model_construction.ModelMetaclass):
        __class_vars__: ClassVar[set[str]]
        __private_attributes__: ClassVar[dict[str, ModelPrivateAttr]]
        __signature__: ClassVar[Signature]

        __pydantic_complete__: ClassVar[bool]
        __pydantic_core_schema__: ClassVar[CoreSchema]
        __pydantic_custom_init__: ClassVar[bool]
        __pydantic_decorators__: ClassVar[_decorators.DecoratorInfos]
        __pydantic_generic_metadata__: ClassVar[_generics.PydanticGenericMetadata]
        __pydantic_parent_namespace__: ClassVar[dict[str, Any] | None]
        __pydantic_post_init__: ClassVar[None | typing_extensions.Literal['model_post_init']]
        __pydantic_root_model__: ClassVar[bool]
        __pydantic_serializer__: ClassVar[SchemaSerializer]
        __pydantic_validator__: ClassVar[SchemaValidator]
```

At first, I thought it's kind of "very private" attributes like we define with `__some_private_attribute`, but e.g. SQLAlchemy Base class is expecting we defined a `__tablename__` attribute. We *need* to give a name.

What is the most appropriate case to use such syntax? I'm not interested in dunder attributes out of box, like `__doc__`, `__dict__`, etc., I want to know when I need to define my own.

Comment: I suspect this is used for metaprogramming. The metaclass looks for these attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, never. From the Python documentation on [Reserved classes of identifiers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#reserved-classes-of-identifiers):

> `__*__`
>
> System-defined names, informally known as “dunder” names. These names are defined by the interpreter and its implementation (including the standard library). Current system names are discussed in the Special method names section and elsewhere. More will likely be defined in future versions of Python. Any use of `__*__` names, in any context, that does not follow explicitly documented use, is subject to breakage without warning.

Pydantic *should* have used a different naming convention, though the odds that Python will ever want to use names of the form `__pydantic_*__` are low, to say the least.

The naming convention *doesn't* tell you what needs to be defined; that's for the documentation to tell you.